# How to use alter command on partitioned table in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created a partitioned table with the below command:

> create table A
>   (
>
> ID number(10),
>
> SUBSCRIBER_TYPE varchar2(20)
>   ,
>
> SSN varchar2(20)
>
> )
>
> ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT
>
> INITRANS 4 STORAGE(FREELISTS 16)
>
> PARTITION BY LIST (SUBSCRIBER_TYPE)
>
> (
>
> ```
> PARTITION P000 VALUES(0),
> PARTITION P001 VALUES(1),
> PARTITION P002 VALUES(2)
> ```
>
> )
>
> TABLESPACE TS_SUBSCRIBER01 ;

Now I need to change the column name `SSN` to `SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER` and its datatype to `number`.

Can I use a simple ALTER command to modify the column of the table so that I it reflects the changes in all the partitions?

Comment: Yes, sure. Are you afraid of something? Why you don't just try it?

Comment: I did using the ALTER command but what happened was, Oracle started to give errors while inserting into the table. So for the confirmation I wanted to post here.

Comment: so, the alter succeeded but inserts fail. What's the error?

Comment: Actually I faced this issue last month so I dropped the table and recreated. But now I face a similar situation in modifying the table. Hence before proceeding further I wanted to verify.

Comment: Ok. The inserts fail. What is the error?

Comment: I don't remember the error exactly but I am sure I faced the error regarding the partition. But anyways I will try again and update the post.

Comment: Hi Florin, its working now without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a simple alter command for the partitioned table.